# How to not have an "expanded" textview?

Tags: ios, swift

I am encountering a small problem that is that my label text is expanded as you can see on the picture below:

[image: Click on this link]

I would like to know how to get normal text please.

If you know how to do that, please let me know.

Here is the code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.updateUserActivityOnApp(isFirstConnection: false)

    //print(self.view.frame.size.height - (self.extraPhoto1.frame.size.height + self.extraPhoto1.frame.origin.y))

    if self.view.frame.size.height - (self.extraPhoto1.frame.size.height + self.extraPhoto1.frame.origin.y) >= 140 {

        descriptionTopSpaceConstraint.constant = 20

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

    profilePicture.image = nil

    descriptionTxtView.isEditable = false

    descriptionTxtView.text! = ""

    extraPhoto1.image = nil

    extraPhoto2.image = nil

    extraPhoto3.image = nil 

    usernameCountryLbl.text! = "Loading..."

    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true)

    var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification")

    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: -0.1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
    self.descriptionTxtView.attributedText = attrStr // label is the UILabel where you want the text to be displayed
    self.descriptionTxtView.sizeToFit()

}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean expanded?

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla well, if you look carefully at the picture, you can see that there are two lines that are written differently, as if there was a larger space between each letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textAligment.natural` as @Rob mentioned is one of the options in case you don't care about your text being justified. Otherwise the only way is to use `NSMutableAttributedString` and `hyphenationFactor`. In case you need it to be justified you can do something like this:

```
    var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification. this is some very long test string for justification")
    var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 1
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.kern, value: -0.1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))
    label.attributedText = attrStr // label is the UILabel where you want the text to be displayed
    label.sizeToFit()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. However, I get this error "Type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'Key'"

Comment: Weird. I'm running the code and is compiling just fine. Can you add the code where you are getting the error? Also, which version of swift are you running?

Comment: I'm running on version 4.0 of swift. If it is the wrong version, could you tell me how to upgrade it?

Comment: I think this should run just fine in swift 4. Please add the code where you are getting the error and I can have a look at the error.

Comment: The code is compiling just fine for me. I am running swift 5 though. I don't really remember the syntax for swift 4.0 but the problem is probably this. Replace: `NSAttributedString.Key` with `NSAttributedStringKey` and I suggest you update Xcode to have the latest swift version

Comment: i changed the wrong line to "attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length))" and it's compiling fine but the result is wrong : I'm getting a really small text on the screen, like a font 5

Comment: yep. Add the font size. Something like: `label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)`

Comment: No worries. BTW try to update Xcode to the latest version. Don't keep programming on Swift 4.0. There have been several changes and if you continue on this version at some point you will have tons and tons of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Set your text view's `textAlignment` to `.natural` instead of `.justified`.